# In which Thread is an Activity called from inside a Runnable?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

If I start a new thread by calling the `start()` method, and then start a new `Activity` from its run method, is my next activity and all the followups activities considered to be in my new `Thread`?

```
Thread test = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Intent n = new Intent(this, SecActivity.class);
        startActivity(n);
    }
});
test.start();
```

Comment: No. A new `Activity` starts on UI thread (a.k.a. main thread). In fact, this thread is not the one that starts the `Activity`. `ActivityManager` is responsible for this that will take care of attaching a new `Activity` to `ActivityThread`.

Comment: Additionally `startActivity()` is NOT a synchronous call, it returns "immediately" letting the system to do the "magic".

Comment: Great , so just to make it clear - if i call some other classes methods they will run on my thread stack calls right? but operations on the system services for example will never run on my new thread?

Comment: Right. Most of the system services run on the `system_server` process and may run on their dedicated threads within the process.